# Spring MVC @RequestMapping dynamic value

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, controller

I am trying to set the "**value**" attribute of `@RequestMapping` annotation from a method of an autowired bean using SpEL

```
@Autowired
private RouteService routeService;

@RequestMapping(value={"#{routeService.loadRoutes()}"})
```

without any success.
Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

**This is happening because the value of the RequestMapping must be a constant expression.**

What you can do is declare some constants and use those as a Strings inside the RequestMapping's value.

Answer (score 0):

Like user OEH said this is not possible. One solution might be to take a path parameter and then route the message based on the value of the parameter.